# Find Children of Specific Page with RefineryCMS and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refinerycms

Right now I have a page with a custom template.

I would like to use a decorator before filter like so in the pages decorator:

```
before_filter :get_gallery_index, :only => [:gallery_main]
```

To define this method I would like to declare something similar to:

```
  def get_gallery_index
    # a = Refinery::Page.where(id: 6).children <- would be ideal
  end
```

Of course, children is not a valid method with Refinery Pages and ActiveRecord. Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can get these records?

Answer (score 0):

Got it by searching through parent_id:

def get_gallery_index
  @gallery_index = Refinery::Page.where(:parent_id => 6)
end